# Connecting remote kafka connection from localhost Spring boot applicaiton

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

My SpringBoot app is running on localhost, but I want it to connect with Kafka that is downloaded on remote server e.g. 123.45.6.789.
I am able to produce and consume messages from the mobaxTerm terminal but my springboot app is not able to connect with kafka due to this error

```
WARN[0;39m [35m18788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntainer#0-0-C-1][0;39m 
[36morg.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [Consumer
 clientId=consumer-fooss-1, groupId=fooss] Connection to node -1 
(localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. 
Broker may not be available.
```

my application.properties file

```
kafka.bootstrapAddress=123.45.6.789:9092
kafka.groupId=fooss
kafka.topicName=topicMyTopic
```

server.properties file

```
    broker.id=0

    listeners=PLAINTEXT://123.45.6.789:9092
    advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://123.45.6.789:9092
    log.segment.bytes=1073741824 
    log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
    zookeeper.connect=123.45.6.789:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
```

I know that there are other questions related to this, and i have read them but i could not find answer to my problem... so please help me in understanding this...

my question is,
Why am i getting an error that says the connection was failed on localhost, even though i am trying to connect to 123.45.6.789 as mentioned in application.properties file?
and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot defaults to using localhost:9092, and it's unclear how you're using `kafka.bootstrapAddress` in your code.

The correct property for automatic configuration is `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I read this tutorial, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka and used kafka.bootstrapAddress as they are using. 
I just changed it to spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers, and it worked. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: You'd need to use `@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")` for that to work

Comment: I was using the exact expression that you have mentioned, but it was not working. 
But now it worked with this: spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers

Comment: Feel free to contribute back to the tutorial. I opened this issue - https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/issues/12755